# Install Windows 8 on VMware Fusion

Tags: windows-8, vmware-fusion

I am currently running Windows 8 in Fusion off Mountain Lion, but Unity is disabled.

I cannot find a way to just download an iso and start a fresh vm. Do I have to order the disk?

Comment: How did you get Windows 8 in the first place?

Comment: Just ran the updater on my 7 machine.

Comment: When you purchased Windows you were sent an email with a link so you can download it.

Comment: That's the updater. I realize that. I've already posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setup a Windows 7 VM and run the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant from there.

Comment: That's what I did. Had a seven vm and ran the updater. Now unity is greyed out and fullscreen doesnt fill the width.

Comment: @mgaughan Unity, the video game development software?

Comment: Unity is a view mode in Fusion where applications run aside the native OS..in the Mac dock, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Found this guy that showed a method of creating an iso.

Suppose I should have started at Microsoft.

[Solution](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_8-windows_install/how-to-clean-install-windows-8/6043a4cd-d62b-4851-86c8-e6c58f8eac90)

Comment: Down-voted based on what?